# How to migrate to Fargate from EC2 in ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am planning to migrate to Fargate for autoscaling purposes. I already have task definitions for both my staging and production environments which are currently live. There's two ways I thought I can migrate to Fargate, either create a new Task Definition to use a Fargate and pretty much use the same configuration that my EC2 instance is using. OR, I can export the concerned Task Definition into JSON and replace the values of `requiredCompatibilities` and `compatibilites` from `EC2` to `FARGATE` and call it a day, and deploy. Don't know if that would work? Here's a sample Task Definition that I have modified to use FARGATE in aforementioned keys. Some redacted data such as environment variables.

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/MY-PROJECT-staging",
          "awslogs-region": "my-region",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8020
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": 300,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": {
        "env": "staging"
      },
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "MY-PROJECT-web-stage"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": null,
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "FARGATE" | Earlier this was EC2
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "task-definition/MY-PROJECT-staging:10",
  "family": "MY-PROJECT-staging",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE" | Earlier this was EC2
  ],
  "networkMode": null,
  "cpu": null,
  "revision": 10,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a new cluster using Fargate, including those in your load balancer, then drain the connections to the EC2 server? Or do something similar using DNS?

Comment: Yes, I am in total control of the application infrastructure, I setup a fargate based task definition and a service as well, it's up now, but the docker container won't run. The network type is `awsvpc` it needs to be bridged for my usecase in order to map host port with container port.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to clearly explain your problem. Please either delete this somewhat vague question or edit the question to more clearly describe your problem getting the docker container to run, including what you've tried, logs, etc.